# perl6 precision base4 conversion

Tags: raku

Perl 6 is losing precision when converting to/from base4. How to retain precision?

```
'0.2322130120323232322110'.parse-base(4)
--> perl6 output :         0.728295262649453
--> high precission value: 0.728295262649453434278257191181182861328125
```

The problem is, when converting `0.728295262649453` to `base(4)`, output is not the original number.

```
0.72829526264945.base(4)
--> output:   0.232213012032323232210333
--> original: 0.2322130120323232322110
```

How to get same values after to/from conversion?

Comment: Floating point numbers are just _approximating_ human style decimal numbers with a sum of (negative) powers of 2.

Comment: @JoopEggen: Perl 6 doesn't use floating point numbers, unless you go out of your way to ask for them.

Comment: @piojo http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/perl/ suggests otherwise, and I cannot imagine Perl 6 being slow on floating point because of some internal emulation. Scalar just is (as in Basic) a catch-all.

Comment: @JoopEggen Perl 6 is considered a different language than Perl 5. The difference is more akin to C => C++ than .NET3.5 => .NET4. That's why the stackoverflow `perl` tag is not applicable to Perl 6 questions. Hence, the link you provided is essentially describing a different language.

Comment: @JoopEggen And I encourage you to take a look at Perl 6. It's really cool. Its killer feature is grammars, which let you easily write code to parse hard stuff, like programming languages. Its type system and dynamic dispatch (including pattern matching, both for dispatch and types) is really cool. Haskell-like, but easier to use. The concurrency capabilities are also quite good.

Comment: Yes grammars I already read about, really phantastic, as I have a languages background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is probably in the way you created your "perl6 output":

```
say "0.2322130120323232322110".parse-base(4)    # 0.72829526264945
```

This is because `say` calls the `.gist` method on whatever it is given.  Or you tried to stringify it (which calls `.Str`, which gives the same result as `.gist`).  If you would call the `.perl` method on the result:

```
say "0.2322130120323232322110".parse-base(4).perl
```

you *do* get the expected `0.728295262649453434278257191181182861328125`.  The `.perl` method returns a string that you could `EVAL` to get the originally given value.

In any case, if you do:

```
say "0.2322130120323232322110".parse-base(4).base(4)
```

you will see that you *do* get back the original value `0.2322130120323232322110`.  I guess this is just a case of just doing it rather than saying it.  :-)

One *could* argue that `.Str` on a `Rat` should use `.perl` instead of `.gist`.  Perhaps that should be a point of attention: it would probably have prevented you from needing to ask this question.